# How to use scanf to read a value without knowing its type

Tags: c

I'm a beginner student. I was asked to write a module that translates user input based on the following rule:

- if character is a letter make it upper case
- if character is a number make it * instead
- if character is a \, the next character will be unaffected

The program must continue to call scanf() to read characters from the user until EOF is encountered.Note: You should be printing characters as soon as you get them. Do not attempt to save them.

Example:

```
input : Hi Mike your room number is \4\2\3 and the passcode is 312
output: HI MIKE YOUR ROOM NUMBER IS 423 AND THE PASSCODE is ***
```

Now my question is: since you don't know what type of character will be entered next, how can you save it in a varaible like scanf("%c", &func) saves the character in func? Also I'm not allowed to use toupper() so how can I make a letter upper case?

Any help is appreciated!!Thanks

Comment: Disallowing `toupper()` seems pretty stupid to me. It forces you to learn and to be bound to a particular character encoding. One step forward, two steps back.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to treat it as a string (or single characters) first. Then, you can check if something is a number by comparing its ASCII code:

```
if(x >= '0' && x <= '9') // digit
```

Similar for the other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the input character by character and the parse it accordingly.
Try this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change();

char ch;

int 
main(void){
    fprintf(stdout, "Input : ");
    for(;;){
        ch = getchar();
        if(ch=='\n')
            break;
        else if(ch=='\\') /* no change */
            ch = getchar();   
        else
            change();
        fprintf(stdout, "%c", ch);
    }
return 0;   
}

void change(){
    if(ch>=97 && ch<=122)   /* small case letters */    
        ch-=32;
    else if(ch>=48 && ch <=57)  /* numbers */    
        ch='*';
}
```