# Translating user input program in C error

Tags: c

I am trying out a program which translates user input based on the below rules:

1. If the character is a letter, it must be printed in upper case.
2. If the character is a number (0-9), an asterisk (*) must be printed instead.
3. If the character is a double quote ("), a single quote (') must be printed instead.
4. If the character is the backslash "\" then it is skipped (not printed), and the next character is printed without any modifications.
5. Otherwise, the character is printed as-is.

**MyCode**

```
#include <stdio.h>


void lowertoupper(char lower)
{
    char upper;

    if(lower >= 'a' && lower <= 'z'){
        upper = ('A' + lower - 'a');
    }
    else{
        upper = lower;
    }

    printf("%c",upper);  
}

int main(void) {
    char chara;
    printf("please enter");

    while(scanf(" %c", &chara)!= EOF)  {
        if ((chara>='a' && chara<='z')||(chara>='A' && chara<='Z'))
        {
            lowertoupper(chara);
        }
        else if (chara>=0 && chara<=9)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        else if (chara=='"')
        {
            printf("'");
        }
        else if (chara=="\\")
        {
        }
        else {
            printf("%c",chara);
        }
    }
}
```

**My questions**

1. This doesn't as expected. What conditions am I missing here.
2. How can I satisfy the condition 4 without using any built in function.

Comment: The format string for `scanf` should not have a space.  In fact there is no need for `scanf` here, use `getchar` instead.  Your first implementation should use the functions `isalpha` and `isdigit` from `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use scanf to read a value without knowing its type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757224/how-to-use-scanf-to-read-a-value-without-knowing-its-type)

Comment: Yes the question is similar, but the code and the scenario here are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int noChange = 0;  /* Added */

while(scanf(" %c", &chara) == 1)  {  /* Modified */
  if(noChange == 1) {    /* Added */
    printf("%c",chara);  /* Added */
    noChange = 0;        /* Added */
  }    /* Added */
  else if ((chara>='a' && chara<='z')||(chara>='A' && chara<='Z'))    /* Modified */
  {
    lowertoupper(chara);
  }
  else if (chara >= '0' && chara <= '9')  /* Modified */
  {
    printf("*");
  }
  else if (chara=='"')
  {
    printf("'");
  }
  else if (chara=='\\')  /* Modified */
  {
    noChange = 1;    /* Added */
  }
  else {
    printf("%c",chara);
  }
}
```

[Working demo here](http://ideone.com/vtaCpe)

Answer (score 1):

This also works, comparing chara stores the ascii value, so ascii value of '0' is not 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char chara = '\0';
    while(scanf("%c", &chara) == 1)  {
        if ( chara>='a' && chara<='z' ) printf("%c",'A' + (chara - 'a'));
        else if (chara >= '0' && chara <= '9') printf("%c",'*');
        else if (chara=='"') printf("%c",'\'');
        else if (chara=='\\') ;
        else printf("%c",chara);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test for digits is problem.  The digit characters are `'0'` through `'1'`, whose actual value depends on the local charset but are never `0` through `9`.